# Accessing a contentpicker field value in Orchard

Tags: .net, orchardcms

So I am using a Content Picker to display a list of selected items, and by default the out put looks like this:

> Testimonial: View, View

But I would like it to actually show the parts of the ContentItem. This is the code that loops through the items:

```
@using Orchard.ContentPicker.Fields
@using Orchard.Utility.Extensions;

@{
    var field = (ContentPickerField) Model.ContentField;
    string name = field.DisplayName;
    var contentItems = field.ContentItems;
}

<p class="content-picker-field content-picker-field-@name.HtmlClassify()">
    <span class="name">@name:</span>
    @if(contentItems.Any()) {
        foreach(var contentItem in contentItems) {
            <span class="value"> @Html.ItemDisplayLink(contentItem)</span>
            if(contentItem != contentItems.Last()) {
                <span>,</span>
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        <span class="value">@T("No content items.")</span>
    }
</p>
```

I've tried several different ways of accessing the data but usually end up with warnings saying that it does not contain a reference, or that it can't convert it to a string.

I know that on the actual page for these items, they're in Model.ContentPart.Quote.Value

---

**Edit**
I think the problem I am having is that I on the main page, I can't go to Models.Content.Quote or anything similar to access the data because its not listed on this page. The only data about each Quote thats listed is the ID.

Comment: Well, technically there is no such thing as "the actual page for these items", but there are several views for its parts. What is the name of the part where you know Model.ContentPart.Quote.Value to work?

Comment: The @Html.ItemDisplalyLink(contentItem) produces a link that directs the user to Contests/Item/Display/**

That page in turn displays the information I want to display on the index, and its accessing ~/Core/Contents/Views/Content.cshtml

Comment: That's not answering my question, which was: in what template did you see Model.ContentPart.Quote.Value working?

Comment: ~/Modules/Orchard.Fields/Views/Fields/Input.cshtml Is what the shape tracer shows, that help?

Comment: OK, what's the name of the content type?

Comment: I'm facing same issue. @jassok: Did you resolve?

Comment: @DharmikBhandari A bit late but see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42514073/3936440)

Answer (score 1):

Simply change `var` to `dynamic` in `foreach`.

Therefore, you change this:

```
foreach(var contentItem in contentItems) {
            <span class="value"> @Html.ItemDisplayLink(contentItem)</span>
            if(contentItem != contentItems.Last()) {
                <span>,</span>
            }
        }
```

to this:

```
foreach(dynamic contentItem in contentItems) {
            <span class="value"> @Html.ItemDisplayLink(contentItem)</span>
            if(contentItem != contentItems.Last()) {
                <span>,</span>
            }
        }
```

Then you can access any part inside `contentItem` like this:

```
contentItem.ZenGalleryPart.Path


foreach(dynamic contentItem in contentItems) {
            <span class="value"> @Html.ItemDisplayLink(contentItem)</span>
            <span class="value"> @T(contentItem.ZenGalleryPart.Path)</span>
            if(contentItem != contentItems.Last()) {
                <span>,</span>
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the following example I have a ContentType **Athlete** which uses a ContentPickerField to select a ContentType **Team**

In a summary view I created for **Athlete** I can access all the parts and fields from the **Team** selected using the ContentPickerField using the code below.

**Content-Athlete.Summary.cshtml**

```
@using Orchard.Utility.Extensions;
@using Orchard.ContentPicker.Fields
@{    
    var teamField = (ContentPickerField) Model.ContentItem.Athlete.Team;    
    //make sure your var is cast (dynamic) and you will have access to all parts/fields
    var team = (dynamic)teamField.ContentItems.First();  
}

@team.TeamPart.City.Value
```

Comment: I have a same problem but your solution not working for me. Please help

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

What you basically need is a **conversion of the content item** (selected in the content picker) **to a shape** to avoid skipping important aspects like [shape alternates](http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Alternates/).

Luckily `BuildDisplay()` is available in views, so you can simply write

```
foreach (var contentItem in contentItems)
{
  @Display(BuildDisplay(contentItem))
}
```

whereas `BuildDisplay()` will create a shape for `contentItem` and `Display()` renders the shape.

If you need specific output for the parts of `contentItem` then you should create an appropriate shape alternate.